# Form submission through JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button in my form that once clicked, a confirmation pops out before submitting the form. However, once submitted, it redirects to the PHP file which processes the inputs and gets stuck there.

**main html/php:**

```
<form id="application-form" name="application-form" action="./php/process-form.php" method="post">
<!--Input boxes etc.-->
<button id="submit-btn" class="submit-btn" name="submit_btn" type="button">Save Application</button>
</form>
```

**js:**

```
const popupCover = document.querySelector('.popup-cover');
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector('.cancel.button');
const confirmBtn = document.querySelector('.confirm.button');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-btn');

confirmBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('application-form').submit();
});

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    popupCover.style.display = 'flex';
});

cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    popupCover.style.display = 'none';
});
```

**php for data insertion:**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST["application-form"])) {
    //Data insertion queries

    header("Location: ../operators.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

It works perfectly just fine when i tried to remove the popup confirmation and changed the button type to submit. Also, I tried using AJAX but it still doesn't submit/process the form.

Comment: You shouldn't have `/>` at the end of `<button`

Comment: There is no `$_POST['application-form']`. `$_POST` only contains inputs, not the name of the form itself.

Comment: Oh sorry for the oversight. I actually don't in my code. I clicked on something while composing the question and it added the "/" on all of my tags. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Right, that's a known bug in the question wizard, it did the same thing in the PHP.

Comment: I already tried changing the button name to name = "submit_form" from the main file and the if (isset($_POST["application-form"])) to if (isset($_POST["submit_form"])) but it's still the same. Upon submission, it gets stuck in the process-form.php.

Comment: Buttons don't get submitted when you use submit from JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm so what should I pass in "if (isset($_POST[""]))" to get the inputs from the form in the main file to be inserted by process-form.php? Cause I already have the submit function in my confirmBtn from my javascript. The only problem is that it gets stuck in process-form.php once submitted.

Comment: Pick one of the inputs. Or leave out the condition entirely, if the script is only ever called from the form.